# NoSuchElementException in Java. Grading Students Problem on Hackerrank

Tags: java

I keep getting error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at Result.gradingStudents(Solution.java:32)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:83)"
```

This was a challenge on hackerrank.I have replaced nextInt() with nextLine() as per some other answers but it doesn't fix the problem.
Also using "hasNext()"/ "hasNextLine()" will just skip asking for input.

I tried an online compiler where I put the code directly in main function, is that the problem, and that worked.

Also tried Buffer reader but that is giving me an error aswell.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

class Result {

public static List<Integer> gradingStudents(List<Integer> grades) 
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of students :");
    int n=0, tempGrade=0;
    
    List<Integer> returnGrades = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    
    String num = scanner.nextLine();
    n = Integer.parseInt(num);
    
    System.out.println("Enter their grades :");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        String tempSGrade = scanner.nextInt();
        tempgrade = Integer.parseInt(tempSGrade);

        grades.add(tempGrade);
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int item = grades.get(i);
        if (item >= 38)
        {
            if((item+2)%5==0)
            {
                item=item+2;
            }
        }
        returnGrades.add(item);
    }

    return returnGrades;
    
}


}

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

    int gradesCount = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());

    List<Integer> grades = IntStream.range(0, gradesCount).mapToObj(i -> {
        try {
            return bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    })
        .map(String::trim)
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .collect(toList());

    List<Integer> result = Result.gradingStudents(grades);

    bufferedWriter.write(
        result.stream()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(joining("\n"))
        + "\n"
    );

    bufferedReader.close();
    bufferedWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to read the user inputs twice as the input values are already being read in the `main` function. So, you don't need to scan the inputs again in the method. You are only supposed to implement the `gradingStudents`.
Your approach for solving the problem also seems to be wrong.
You can find the next multiple of `5` as:

```
int nextMultipleOf5 = (item/5 + 1) * 5;
```

Comment: Thanks ! I should've just paid attention to the entire code rather than assuming that I need to get the input aswell.